# The CorrelationMatrix is equal to corrcoef of Matlab?

Tags: matrix, fitting, matlab

How can I generate a matrix which is equivalent to the results of the "correlation coefficients" command ([corrcoef](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html)) in Matlab?

When I make a LinearModelFit, I can get a CorrelationMatrix, but is this the same as the matrix give by Matlab with corrcoef? If not, what can I do make it so?

Comment: Nobody knows? or is too dumb to bother ?

Comment: It's not a dumb question but it is difficult to verify without both software packages and the right expertise.  I do know that the Mathematica property is the correlation  of the parameters ( the diagonal of the covariance matrix property is their variances) a brief look at the docs for the matlab function makes me think it is more akin to mathematicas Correlation function rather than the fitted model property.